# matplotlib heatmap with separated columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a heatmap plot with multiple columns, that looks like this:

[image: Example Heatmap plot]

This is nearly exactly what I want. I used imshow to do it, the plotting code is very simple, with data as a 2D numpy array:

```
plt.imshow(data, cmap="hot", 
               vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, aspect='auto',  
               interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Ideally, though, the columns in this headmap should be grouped (or broken out), as they represent related things.  Is there any easy way to create a version of this plot where I can, say, separate columns 0-4, 5-10, and 11-22 into separate blocks, without repeating the colorbar or the yaxis label, but with possible unique labels for each set of columns?

Ideally I'd like a plot that looks like (in ascii art):

```
0   +---+   +-------+  +-------------+   +-+ 1.0
    |   |   |       |  |             |   | | 
500 |   |   |       |  |             |   | |
    |   |   |       |  |             |   | |
1000+---+   +-------+  +-------------+   +-+ 0.0
     L1      Label2       Label3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily slice your `data` array [using standard numpy array notation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

After that it's just a matter of creating your axes with the right geometry. [You could use Gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html?highlight=gridspec) for that, or the sightly simpler [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) version.

```
data = np.random.random(size=(1000,22))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True,gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[5,6,12]})
a1 = axs[0].imshow(data[:,:5], cmap="hot", 
               vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, aspect='auto',  
               interpolation='nearest')
a2 = axs[1].imshow(data[:,5:10], cmap="hot", 
               vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, aspect='auto',  
               interpolation='nearest')
a3 = axs[2].imshow(data[:,11:], cmap="hot", 
               vmin=0.0, vmax=1.0, aspect='auto',  
               interpolation='nearest')

for ax,l in zip(axs,['Label 1','Label 2','Label 3']):
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_xlabel(l)

plt.colorbar(a1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that's exactly what I needed.  sharey and gridspec was what I was missing. I knew I could carve it up easily, but I couldn't match the resulting plots.  Thank you!